# 2 segues from one view controller

Tags: ios, swift

I have 2 buttons on my main view controller. Clicking on either button would first collect some data and then later opens respective ViewController.

I call performSegue(withIdentifier:"logInfo",sender: self) in action function of buttons.

I am using segue.identifier as below,

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if(segue.identifier == "logInfo") {....}
    else if(segue.identifier == "getInfo") {....}
}
```

However, on clicking second button both ViewControllers open back to back. How can I stop this?

**UPDATE:**

```
func onClickCell(index: Int) {
    if(condition) {
       self.performSegue(withIdentifier:"displayInfo",sender: self)
    } else {
       //something else
    }
}

func logCell(index: Int) {
    if(condition) {
       self.performSegue(withIdentifier:"logInfo",sender: self)
    } else {
       //something
    }
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if(segue.identifier == "logInfo") {...} 
    else if(segue.identifier == "displayInfo"){...}
}
```

[image]

Comment: How are you triggering the segues? `prepare(for:)`is called after the segue is triggered, it doesn't trigger the segue itself.

Comment: Its for sending the data I collected

Comment: What I mean is are you calling `performSegue(with:)` in code or have you linked the segue to the action of the button in your storyboard?  That is where you have to look because if you are getting both segues firing from the second button it means you have somehow linked both segues to that button.  It is nothing to do with the code you have shown.

Comment: On storyboard, I have segues in between the view controllers but I am not triggering them from the buttons.

Comment: so Are you triggering them from code? Can you show that code?

Comment: What does "back to back" actually mean in the context of view controllers?

Comment: Look for update. "Back to back" means that both view controllers open one after other.

Comment: You must be calling both of those functions in the case of your second button. Those aren't @IBAction, so how do those functions get called when the buttons are tapped?  Set a breakpoint in the relevant function to work out how it is being called. It helps if you provide all relevant information and code on how your program is operating

Comment: Could be http://www.programmingios.net/double-segue-mistake/